# Oracle SQL query to extract the insert record for last 3hours

Tags: oracle

Consider i have the table A which doesn't store the timestamp of the new rows inserted. Is there any query to get the count of rows inserted on the table A for the specified time frame. EX: Get records between 6 PM to 9 PM yesterday or get the record count inserted in last 4hrs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ORA_ROWSCN` pseudo column to get the system change number of the last operation (not insert) on your table --> Convert it to `timestamp` and then use it in `WHERE` clause to get the desired data as follows:

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) LAST_OPERATION_TIME,
       T.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) BETWEEN START_TIMESTAM AND END_TIMESTAMP;
```

You can learn more about the `ORA_ROWSCN` from [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If there are archive logs for the search period. You must use the utility LogMiner.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39306_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.NEW); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39307_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39308_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39309_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);

SELECT 
to_char(timestamp,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
operation,username,  
os_username,
machine_name,
session_info,
sql_redo

 FROM v$logmnr_contents
where 
seg_owner='MANAGER' and  seg_name='TEST2'

02-07-2020 09:40:20 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  create table test2 (p1 number);
02-07-2020 09:40:47 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c117'));
02-07-2020 09:40:53 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c119'));
02-07-2020 09:40:57 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c137'));
02-07-2020 09:41:01 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c20219'));
02-07-2020 09:41:45 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  alter table test2 add (p2 varchar2(200));
02-07-2020 09:42:12 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c20219'),HEXTORAW('746573743220746573743120'));
02-07-2020 09:42:24 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
02-07-2020 09:46:24 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
02-07-2020 09:46:25 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
02-07-2020 09:46:26 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
02-07-2020 09:46:27 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
02-07-2020 09:46:28 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
02-07-2020 09:54:37 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN   comment on table test2 is  'test';
02-07-2020 10:16:36 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  alter table test2 add  (p3 varchar2(100));
02-07-2020 10:17:07 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("P1","P2","P3") values ('125','test6','test4 ');
02-07-2020 10:17:08 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV HOME\DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=HOME\DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("P1","P2","P3") values ('125','test6','test4 ');
'
```